# bootstrap-navwalker will not load

Tags: menus

[image]Trying to implement `wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php` into my made from scratch template for wordpress.
The File for the `class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php` is located in the root directory of my theme.

**functions.php**

```
function register_navwalker()
 {
  require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';<br>
 }
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );
```

register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'primary' ),
) );

**cover.php**
With the code below within the `<nav> and </nav>` tags

```
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'top-menu',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
    ) );
    ?>
```

When I save changes and reload my website, I get get the wp-bootstrap-navwalker page from github.

I've checked the source of the page and see this at the footer:
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker' not found in C:\laragon\www\VzyulTech\wp-content\themes\Version2\index.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\VzyulTech\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include()
#1 C:\laragon\www\VzyulTech\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\laragon\www\...')
#2 C:\laragon\www\VzyulTech\index.php(17): require('C:\laragon\www\...')
#3 {main}
thrown in **C:\laragon\www\VzyulTech\wp-content\themes\Version2\index.php** on line **17**

When I check line 17 it is the 'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),

```
        wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
    ) );
```

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `register_navwalker` function is loading `navwalker` with this line:

```
require_once get_template_directory() . './class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
```

where you concatenate the path of the theme with this string:

```
'./class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php'
```

and the dot there at the beginning is a problem. The result would look like this:

```
DOMAIN/wp-content/themes/THEME./class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php
```

remove the dot and it should find and load the script.

**EDIT:**

Also you shouldn't change your original post or question, but add to it. Otherwise comments and answers might not make sense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Place class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php in your WordPress theme folder /wp-content/your-theme/

Open your WordPress themes functions.php file - /wp-content/your-theme/functions.php - and add the following code:

If you encounter errors with the above code use a check like this to return clean errors to help diagnose the problem.

```
    function register_navwalker()
    {
       if ( ! file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php' ) ) {
       // file does not exist... return an error.
       return new WP_Error( 'class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker-missing', __( 'It appears the class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php file may be missing.', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) );
      } else {
        // file exists... require it.
        require_once get_template_directory . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
    }
  } 
  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );
```

You will also need to declare a new menu in your functions.php file if one doesn’t already exist.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'top-menu' => __( 'Top Menu', 'THEMENAME' ),
) );
```

**Usage** :
Add or update any wp_nav_menu() functions in your theme (often found in header.php) to use the new walker by adding a 'walker' item to the wp_nav_menu args array.

```
   <?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'    => 'top-menu',
    'depth'             => 2,
    'container'         => 'div',
    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My apoligies, I have been able to resolve the problem.

What I did wrong was go to: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker and on the php file for the wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php, i had right click and saved the file. I then opened the the file in a notepad and noticed it began with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```